# Reduce phone charger values

Tags: integrated-circuit

I’m trying to modify the output of an old Motorola  phone charger which is rated 5V 500mA.  I want to modify it’s output to 1.2V 150mA to charge a small battery.

Can this be done?

I can’t open the charger because it is sealed.  Can it be done with resistors or diodes?

Comment: You could design a NiCd 1/10C trickle charger with just a ballast resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should give as much detail as possible about the battery specification.
A photo also may help.

A "1.2V" battery probably needs other than 1.2V to charge it.

Once we know what the battery needs we can advise of how a charger can be constructed using your existing power supply.  Some form of (probably very simple) linear regulator will probably do the job.

Something from [here](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ACYBGNTNy4trofF639PuekU97Khpo5CNEQ:1574124548839&q=lm317+battery+charger&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd-8L0hvXlAhXIfX0KHfUQAK8QsAR6BAgMEAE&biw=3413&bih=1763&dpr=1.13) will probably suffice. Which one depends on your battery.

Something like this **with appropriate component values** will quite possibly meet your requirement. (The component values shown are not at all suited to your requirement).

[image]

From [here](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/12v-battery-charger-circuit-diagram-using-lm317)

Something even simpler will probably work if absolute minimum cost and/or simplicity is required.

Comment: Hi again thanks for the answer, the original charger for the battery was a small transformer that had on it's label, 110v to 1.2v 150ma